# Dynamically Select CSS label

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap

this is my code snippet

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <% @posts.each do |post| %>
            <h1><a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>"><%= post.title %></a></h1>
            <p><%= post.body %></p>
            <div>
              <span class="badge"><%= calculate_time_difference(Time.now - post.updated_at)%></span>
              <span class="badge"><a href="/posts/<%= post.id %>/like">Like this post!</a></span>
              <span class="badge">Likes: <%= post.like_count %></span>
              <% post.tags.each do |tag| %>
              <% ["label-default", "label-primary", "label-success", "label-info", "label-danger", "label-warning"].each do |label| %>
              <!-- problematic part here -->
              <div class="pull-right"><span class="label <%= label %>"> <a href="/tags/<%= tag.name %>"><%= tag.name %></a></span></div>
          <%end%>
    <% end %>
    <hr>
    <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

how can I select dynamically class label in post and tag loops?

Comment: What is the problem? Is `class="label <%= label %>"` not interpolating correctly?

Comment: yes. problem is, repetitive same tag results. in other words, same tag is looping two or three times.

Comment: OK. I solved it.  <% labels  = ["label-success", "label-info", "label-primary",   "label-danger", "label-default", "label-warning"]  %> <% post.tags.each_with_index do |tag, index| %> <% label = labels[index] %>
   how can I select label randomly. I think like this  <% label = labels[rand(index)] %> but it is not working.